# VB MVC Re-using a partial view for multiple models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, partial-views

I have a bunch of models that contain audit info (CreatedBy, CreateDate, UpdatedBy, UpdateDate). I'd like to create a partial view for displaying this info and then use it for the 20 or so tables. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface or base class with those properties, then declare the partial view as taking that common type.